# What is the best way to transport database fields from one database to another?

Tags: mysql

I have two databases. The table name and fields name are different and field numbers are unequal. I need to transport all fields from one database to another. I can import the database as CSV format.

I can use a PHP script which will accomplish this.

But is there any other way to do this easily without any script.

Comment: Two databases on the same server or on two different servers?

Comment: Are all the tables MyISAM ???

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot different server.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA yes they are both MYISAM

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following scenario:

- On DBServer1, Database `db1` contains MyISAM tables only
- On DBServer2, Database `db2` is the target database
- `/var/lib/mysql` is datadir for both DB Servers
- 10.2.3.40 is the IP address of DBServer1

You could copy the MyISAM tables straight to the target database

From DBServer2, run these Linux commands

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/db2
scp IPADDRofServer1:/var/lib/mysql/db1/*.frm /var/lib/mysql/db2/.
scp IPADDRofServer1:/var/lib/mysql/db1/*.MYD /var/lib/mysql/db2/.
scp IPADDRofServer1:/var/lib/mysql/db1/*.MYI /var/lib/mysql/db2/.
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/db2/.
```

That's it. No SQL Processing of any kind. The information_schema database on DBServer2 will autodetect the presence of new MyISAM and incorporate them accordingly.

Give it a Try !!!

**CAVEAT** : THIS DOES NOT WORK InnoDB TABLES AT ALL !!!

Comment: +1 but isn't it advisable to use `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` before moving MyISAM tables around?  Just in case there's some unflushed data in the filesystem cache.

Comment: @BillKarwin Perhaps shutdown and cold backup would be better. Stupid MyISAM !!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will help that I used to prefix table names

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',db,'.',prfx,tb,' LIKE ',db,'.',tb,';', -- copy structure
    'INSERT INTO ',db,'.',prfx,tb,' SELECT * FROM ',db,'.',tb,';') -- copy data
FROM
    (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb
     FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
     table_schema in (DB_NAME)
    ) A,
    (SELECT 'test_' prfx) B;
```